# Rolify + CanCanCan: Prevent 'admin' user to change/create 'superadmin'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, cancancan, rolify

I'm using rolify, CanCanCan and devise.

I have 3 types of users:
- Superadmin
- Admin
- Normal

I want to prevent "Admin" users to change a user to "superadmin" role or create/change a user with "superadmin" role.

What's the best way to do this?In the Ability class or with a before_filter of some kind?

Here's my Ability file simplified with only the user part:

```
class Ability
    include CanCan::Ability
    def initialize(user)

       alias_action :create, :read, :update, :destroy, :to => :crud

       user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

       if user.has_role? :normal
           can :read, User
       elsif user.has_role? :admin
           can :crud, User
       elsif user.has_role? :superadmin
           can :manage, :all
       else
           cannot :manage, :all
       end
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on documentation [here](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks#block-conditions-with-scopes)

```
cannot :edit, User, User.all do |user|
    user.has_role?(:superadmin)
end
```